# Bounded sequence satisfying an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $(x_n)_n$ be a bounded sequence . Assume that $x_{n+1} \ge x_n-\frac{1}{2^n}$. Show that $(x_n)_n$ is convergent.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that
$$
x_{n+1}\ge x_n-\frac{1}{2^n}\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad x_{n+1}-\frac{1}{2^n}\ge x_n-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}.
$$
Hence, the sequence $y_n=x_n-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ is increasing. It is also bounded, since it is the sum of two bounded sequences, and hence $\{y_n\}$ is convergent, and so is $\{x_n\}$ as the sum of two convergent sequences.

Comment: Pretty ingenious! +1